# installing glassfish server in linux

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish

I want to get glassfish server up and running on ubuntu. I was able to install it but when I'm trying to start it with:

```
./asadmin start-domain domain1
```

I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized option: -XX
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `<jvm-option>`s in domain1/config/domain.xml and make sure they're supported by your JDK.